# Java: Casting a List<?> without warning

Tags: java, generics, casting

Assume we have following example code.

First Class:

```
public class Template<T> {

    private final T val;

    public Template(T val) {
        this.val = val;
    }

    public T getVal() {
        return val;
    }
}
```

Second class:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<?> templates = new ArrayList<Template<?>>();

        // How can I cast this without warning?
        List<Template<?>> castedTemplates = (List<Template<?>>)templates;

        // further code...
    }
}
```

So, my question is: How can I do the cast without warning and without *@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")*?

Comment: You can't......

Comment: Guess you'll have to live with the warning.  It's not like it stops your compile, does it?

Comment: No, the compiler just reports a compile warning.

Comment: If you want to use Generic properly then why are you using `?` here? Try with `Object` if you don't know the type.

Answer (score 2):

Why would you if you can just define it as `List<Template<?>> templates = new ArrayList<Template<?>>();`?

Comment: I personally wouldn't consider this an answer... It is very much phrased as a question, although I do understand the rhetorical nature of it.

Comment: @Uxonith Agreed, should've used a comment.

Comment: In this example this would be certainly a solution. That's right, of course. But it's not a solution in my real world code, because the `List<?>` type is coming from a not changeable interface.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do it.

This is the point - the compiler has to generate those warnings so that they warn you that you're doing something not quite by the book.

And the `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` is supposed to suppress them (if that's what you explicitly want).

I know it sounds too trivial as an answer but it's true.